# PNG image not showing up when using Tkinter + Pillow (PIL) in Python 2.7 under Mac OS

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

I would like to show a *PNG image* in user-interface using `Python's Tkinter` and `Pillow's ImageTk`. This works just fine in Windows OS but fails in Mac OS. In Mac, it opens a empty window corresponding to size of the PNG image and doesn't show any error.

I see that, if PNG image is directed using **Button**, it works fine but fails when using **Label** (of course, I need it to show using label). However, opening image with Label works if image is in *gif* format.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import urllib, cStringIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("")

file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png').read())
img = Image.open(file)

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
xxx= Label(root, image = photo)      # Not working in Mac
# xxx= Button(root, image = photo)   # This works in Mac
xxx.grid(row=14, column=0, rowspan = 5)
# img.show()        # opens perfectly using 'Preview' application in Mac

root.mainloop()
```

I tested the above code in Windows where everything plays nice. Am I missing something or this is an inherent problem when using pillow in Mac? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, and solved by this

`photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img).convert('RGB')`

But this will drop the alpha layer

Comment: I think you mean `ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.convert("RGB"))`, convert is a method on `PIL.Image`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it worked for me.

```
photo = PhotoImage(...)

label = Label(image=photo)

label.image = photo # keep a reference!

label.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks!! This also works for attaching an image to a Button control